# Changing tag based on category in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm inputting the category number of a post into a JavaScript function to return the respective text.

```
function catCall(type) {
    if(type == 0) {
        var cat = "News";
        $("#tagCall").val(cat);
    } else if(type == 1) {
        var cat = "Gaming";
        $("#tagCall").val(cat);
    } else if(type == 2) {
        var cat = "Movies";
        $("#tagCall").val(cat);
    } else if(type == 3) {
        var cat = "Sci/Tech";
        $("#tagCall").val(cat);
    }
    else { } 
}

<div onload="catCall('<?php echo $main['cat']; ?>')">
    <span class="tag">
        <div id="tagCall"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

This combination doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: `#tagCall` is a DIV, it has no value, maybe you wanted to use `text()` instead of `val()` ?

Comment: @adeneo, updated it and still not working - any other ideas?

Comment: can you tell us what `function catCall(type) { alert(JSON.stringify(type)) ` shows exactly? Maybe there is an error

Comment: The DIV doesn't really have an `onload` event either, so the function never fires.

Comment: can you tell me value $main['cat'] for these?

Comment: @CodeiSir Just updated with that line, not getting an alert - I think adeneo is on to something, let me try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the function a string instead of a number, do it like that:

```
catCall(<?php echo $main['cat']; ?>)">
```

**Also consider:**

#tagCall is a DIV, it has no value, maybe you wanted to use text() instead of val() (by @adeneo)

**And:**

The DIV doesn't really have an onload event either, so the function never fires. (by @adeneo)

In the end you want to do it like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="tag">
        <div id="tagCall"></div>
    </span>
    <script>catCall(<?php echo $main['cat']; ?>)</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks!